# simultaneous connection to two networks

Tags: networking, wifi

I have the following setup - 
a smartphone tethering (broadcasting an ad-hoc wifi network) internet and a router broadcasting a (local, no-internet) network which has my server. the reason i do this is that phone will time after time, crash under heavy lifting.
I can currently connect to the server and be offline, or switch and connect to the internet - with no access to the server.

What's the best way to integrate both networks, so that I can both browse the internet and work simultaneously.

Thanks!

Comment: This is also called dual-homing and is considered a major security risk. Whatever is passed to your Internet facing laptop could be passed to you internal server. If this is a work environment I would STRONGLY disagree with doing this ... but it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this under windows?

Type something like this in cmd.

route add 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.10 if 2

Replace 192.168.1.10 with your servers address and the number 2 with the number of your NIC.

You may have to specify your default route to use the wireless nic instead of the wired, I'm not sure how windows usually defaults two interfaces.

Comment: This is called a "routing metric", and can be set under any OS. Just google for it.

Comment: It's not a 'routing metric'. It's just a route. 'Routing Metrics' are the priority of routes, he's just using the default priority (as opposed to default route), as he didn't specify one.